# CTE in kdb recursive query

Tags: recursion, common-table-expression, kdb

Following is the CTE example in sql server. I have to do similar recursion in KDB. Is KDB support recursive queries or something close to it. Currently i can think of creating functions and hold the temporary data of each recursion into something...

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
WITH DirectReports(ManagerID, EmployeeID, Title, EmployeeLevel) AS 
(
    SELECT ManagerID, EmployeeID, Title, 0 AS EmployeeLevel
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees 
    WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.ManagerID, e.EmployeeID, e.Title, EmployeeLevel + 1
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e
        INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d
        ON e.ManagerID = d.EmployeeID 
)
SELECT ManagerID, EmployeeID, Title, EmployeeLevel 
FROM DirectReports
ORDER BY ManagerID;
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do but two useful recursive keywords in kdb are

```
over
```

and

```
scan
```

If you are only interested in the final result of the recursion you use over:

ex.

```
q){x+2*y} over 2 3 5 7
32
```

but if you want the output from each step, use scan:

ex.

```
q){x+2*y} scan 2 3 5 7
2 8 18 32
```

These are both examples from Jeff Borror's q for mortals. More here: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/control/#over